# youtube use python to get details from a url

Tags: python, youtube

using python:
-search for youtube by keywords. ex: best movies
-and list only in a txt url videos that have a site:www in the description.
-and export in a txt or xlsx be specific like this:

video:
title:
date of publication:
domain:

can this be done using python ?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: This sounds to me sort of like a web scraping activity, so I would suggest looking into Scrapy, Beautiful Soup, or Selenium.